# Rails postgres Time attribute not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone

Am I going insane? `time` attributes lose their value and reset to January 1 2000 after saving the active record object. The db is Postgres. Rails 5.2 and pg gem 1.1.3

```
2.6.6 :019 > obj.end_time = Date.new(2019, 9,9)
 => Mon, 09 Sep 2019 
2.6.6 :020 > obj.save
 => true 
2.6.6 :021 > obj.end_time
 => Mon, 09 Sep 2019 00:00:00 UTC +00:00 
2.6.6 :022 > obj.end_time.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

But now if I reload from the db, the value is reset:

```
2.6.6 :023 > obj.reload
2.6.6 :024 > obj.end_time
 => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
2.6.6 :025 > obj.end_time.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

The postgres column type is shown in psql as "time without time zone". I guess I just need to specify datetime instead of time in migrations if I want to set the date part?

I tried to change column type in a migration `change_column :school_courses, :start_time, :datetime` but got:

> PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "start_time" cannot be cast
> automatically to type timestamp without time zone HINT:  You might
> need to specify "USING start_time::timestamp without time zone"

Not sure how to do this

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with a basic model, are you doing something in your model class which might affect this?

Comment: Must be something to do with the column type in Postgres. I've nothing in the model and it's happening elsewhere. Will try check in psql

Comment: Then it would be helpful for you  post the model and the postgres table definitions (DDL).

Comment: In Rails the schema just says "time" for the column. Running \d in psql on the table gives the column type as "time without time zone" as I mentioned. Is there another psql command you recommend that might give more information?

Comment: @rigyt can you please post how you wrote your working migration (solution)?

Comment: @thefonso see migration example added to answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime` column type to hold a date and time
Only use `time` in the migration if you don't need the date (only want to store time part)

This is the case with postgres anyway

Migration example:

```
create_table "school_years" do |t|
    t.integer "year"
    t.integer "minimum_candidates_per_exam"
    t.time "am_start_time"
    t.time "pm_start_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Although I generally just use `datetime` and set the year part as well, and avoid using `time`

Comment: Thank you for responding. Did you ever use the hint described "HINT: You might need to specify "USING start_time::timestamp without time zone"" inside the migration itself with the USING keyword?